# Extending the concept of distribution function to any totally or partially ordered measurable space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, order-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space. Let $(Y,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space. Let $X:(\Omega,\mathcal A) \to (Y, \Sigma)$ be a random variable. Then $X$ has probability measure $\mu_X = P \circ X^{-1}$, also called the *distribution* of $X$, in the probability space, also called the *distribution space*, $(Y, \Sigma, \mu_X)$.

In Wikipedia and other Google search, the concept of a *distribution function* $F_X: Y \to [0,1]$ in [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function_(measure_theory)) and [probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Definition) seems to be limited to the case where $Y = \Re$, where

$$F_X(t) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq t\})$$

For example this [Wikipedia definition of distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function_(measure_theory)) is limited to $Y= \Re$:

> Let $ \mu $ be a measure on the real numbers, equipped with the Borel
> $\sigma$-algebra. Then the function $$ F_\mu \colon \Re \to \Re \cup \{ +\infty, - \infty \} $$ defined by $$ F_\mu(t)= \begin{cases} \mu((0,t]) & \text{if } t\geq 0 \\ -\mu((t,0]) & \text{if } t < 0\end{cases}$$ is called the (right continuous) distribution function
> of the measure $ \mu $.

Similarly, in [these lecture notes on measure theory](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Emd3405/DT_Risk_2_15.pdf), the concept of a *distribution function* $F: Y \to [0,1]$ is limited to domain $\Re$:

> **Definition 4.** A map $F:\Re\to[0,1]$ is said to be a distribution function if it is increasing, right continuous and $F(-\infty) = 0 = 1-F(\infty)$.

even though the concept of a *distribution* $\mu: \Sigma \to [0,1]$ is stated more generally:

> **Definition 7.** Let $Y$ be a metric space. A $Y$-valued random variable on a probability space $(X,\Sigma,p)$ induces a Borel probability measure on $Y$ as follows:  $$p_x(S) = p(x^{-1}(S))$$ for every $S \in B(Y)$.  This is the **distribution** of $x$.  If $Y =\Re$, then we call this the **distribution function** of $x$.

*Q.* Can the restriction of $Y$ to $\Re$ be lifted in case $Y$ has a total or partial order?  This is exactly the point I am trying to generalize.  In place of "If $Y=\Re$" I want to say "If $Y$ is totally ordered" or "If $Y$ is partially ordered" or something of this nature which indicates that $Y$ has enough order to define a *distribution function* as opposed to a *distribution*.  **This is the essence of the question, no more no less.**  The above definition seems to work fine for any [totally ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) $Y$.  Actually, since only $\leq$ is involved, it seems that we really only need $Y$ to be [partially ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Comment: With the level of abstraction given, in a purely mathematical context (i.e. without considering an application domain like game theory), can you give the conditions on measurable space $(S,\Sigma)$ such that $F_X(t) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq t\})$ is a cumulative distribution function, for $t \in S$, so $F_X: S \to [0,1]$?

Comment: What do you mean? For any probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ and any measure space $(S,\Sigma)$, as long as  there is a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow S$ that is $\mathscr{F}$-$\Sigma$ measurable (i.e. $X^{-1}(V)=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in V\}\in\mathscr{F}$ for all $V\in\Sigma$), the set function $\mathbb{P}_X$ defined on $\Sigma$ as $\mathbb{P}_X(A)=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$ is a probability measure on $(S,\Sigma)$. I only pointed out that the is interest in considering $(S,\Sigma)$ as totally order space comes from problems in decision theory and economics.

Comment: The predicate $X(\omega) \leq t$ requires at least a partial order.  This is for a distribution function $F_X: S \to [0,1]$, which is distinct from a distribution $\mu_X: \Sigma \to [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for the paper!  I am looking for the conditions to define the distribution function. Suppose $\Omega=\{a,b\}$ and $X(\omega)=\omega$ is my random variable, and $P[\{a\}]=P[\{b\}] = \frac{1}{2}$. There is no order defined on $\Omega$ so I can't form the sets $\{x : x < t\}$.  I need $\Omega$ to be provided with an order relation $<$.  Otherwise this is a case where I have a probability space with a distribution but without a distribution function.  So the question is (a) Do I need an order $<$ to define a CDF? (I think Yes).  (b) Can it be partial? (I guess No, it has to be total.)

Comment: I'm not trying to impose order.  I'm just saying that in the usual presentation of CDF, it is assumed that random variable $X: \Omega \to \Re$.  $\Re$ is ordered.  This allows to define the CDF which is $F: \Re \to [0,1]$.  CDF depends on the presence of an order, it's in the definition.  I'm not asking a deep question or trying to impose anything on anything.  I'm just asking what I need to have when I want to extend the idea of a CDF to other $S$ other than $\Re$.  It's really a simple question.

Comment: It just so happens that the distribution (by that I mean the push-fowrard of $\mathbb{P}$ by $X$, $\mu\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A))$  of a real valued random variable $X$ is completely determined by the function $F_X(u)=\mathbb{P}[X\leq u]$, $u\in\mathbb{R}$,  known as the cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $X$. That is the extent to which one considers cdf's.  That does not mean that any probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is related to an order (partial or total) on $\Omega$ that is somehow compatible to the structure in $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: To my understanding, I can construct a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ and random variable $X: \Omega\to S$, where $(S,\Sigma)$ is some measurable space, which has $\mu\mathbb P$ but not $F_X$.  The definition $F_X(u) = \mathbb P[X \leq u]$ depends on a relation $\leq$ being defined on the range $S$ of $X: \Omega\to S$.  It doesn't have to be, and $F_X$ doesn't have to exist.  So the question is, if $S$ happens to have an ordering relation $\leq$, does it have to be a total order or can it be a partial order, for $F_X$ to be a CDF.

Comment: I would think that total order together with separability assumptions would be necessary. As for sufficiency, you may try to mimic the construction of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $\mathbb{R}$ starting from a "CDF" and see for yourself if that can be done. See the construction in Cohn's Measure theory for instance (Proposition 1.3.9 on page 19). The CDF should be right continuous. This is why separability would be required.

Comment: I'm surprised  this is not in a book as a standard generalization of the idea of a CDF.  To give a sense of where I'm coming from: For my idea of random variable I am referring to Remark 1 on page 8 of http://www.columbia.edu/~md3405/DT_Risk_2_15.pdf.  He defines the usual CDF in Definition 4 on page 6.  He defines a general distribution in Definition 7 page 9.  Only in case $Y=\Re$ does he call it a distribution function. This is the spot where I think restricting to the case of $\Re$ is too specific and $Y$ could be any metric space with something like "total order with separability".

Comment: Closing in on it, this comment seems evocative: "In Wheeden and Zygmund, the "distribution function" is defined for finite measure spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ as $\mu(\{f > \lambda\})$. https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Measure_and_Probabili/jiMRBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=distribution%20

Comment: In WZ (and in many books on Analysis) $f\geq0$ and the measure induced by $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, when $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu$ is fully characterize by the map $\lambda\mapsto\mu(f>\lambda)$, similar as to what happens in probability with CDFs. It seems you are too worked up with the word distribution.

Comment: I will add some examples in the problem statement to show the point I am trying to generalize.  In any event though it's likely to be in Chapter 4 of this book: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Probabilistic_Metric_Spaces/8LUd6Txuu5sC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=distribution%20functions

Comment: As for Remark 1 on p.8, which refers to measurability, hidden is the fact that the collection of intervals $(-\infty,a]$ generate the whole Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}$. That is possible because of separability. There is nothing restrictive with working with $\mathbb{R}$. In a precious bounty of yours, I mentioned to you a deep theorem that established the "measurable" equivalence between $\mathbb{R}$ (or $(0,1)$) and complete separable metric spaces. That is why $\mathbb{R}$, for the most part, is enough.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at that reference.  The bounty question led to this question because I am still trying to separate out the idea of probability space as an indexing space for a domain of interest (some measurable space) from the measurable space which is the "real world" domain of some experiment (for example a pair of dice).  Part of getting my head around that separation is this question of generalizing the concept of distribution function to non-$\Re$ domains. The bounty was difficult to award because all answers were great, so I went with the one that responded in form Q1/Q2/Q3.

Comment: CDFs are defined only for $\mathbb{R}$ (even for $\mathbb{R}^n)$ and are used for convenience. The push-forward is of a measure $\mu$ by a Radom variable $X:(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)\rightarrow(S,\Sigma)$, $\mu_X(A):=\mu(X\in A)$ is the object of interest and it is as general as it can be, since $(S,\Sigma)$ has no structure other than being a measurable space.

Comment: I've clarified the question by quoting the specific texts I am looking at.  If the CDF concept can't be generalized to a domain other than $\Re$ that has an order $\leq$, please answer the question in the negative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111447/discussion-between-oliver-diaz-and-lars-ericson).

Answer (score 0):

**Straw man answer.** This question isn't attracting answers, so I'll do the best I can.  If you downvote this answer, please give your rationale in the comments or provide a better answer.

Let

- $(Y, d)$ be a metric space
- $(X, \Sigma, P)$ be a probability space
- $V: (X, \Sigma) \to (Y,d)$ be a $Y$-valued random variable
- $V^{-1}(E) = \{x \in X: V(x) \in E\}$ be the generalized inverse of $V$
- $\mu_V(E) = P(V^{-1}(E))$ be the *distribution*
- $F_V(E) = P(\{x \in X: V(x) \leq e\})$ be the *distribution function*

Clearly $F_V(E)$ is well defined for any metric space $(Y,d)$ provided with a relation $a \leq b$ for all $a,b \in Y$.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429373/why-is-there-no-order-in-metric-spaces):

- All metric spaces can be totally ordered.
- Not all metric spaces have a total order which is "compatible with the ring structure".  (So: not sensible or useful in that specific sense.)  For example, the complex numbers $\mathbb C$.

So in the strict sense that all metric spaces can be totally ordered, the distribution function always exists, but it may be "uninteresting".

So to be "obviously useful", it is only necessary to stipulate that the metric space $(Y,d)$ is an "obviously useful" ordered metric space.  Here we have range of possible more or less useful orderings:

- $Y$ is a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)
- $Y$ has a partial order compatible with the ring structure
- $Y$ is a [totally ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)
- $Y$ is a [Complete metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space)

Following this [discussion in Zulip](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/How.20do.20I.20tell.20Lean.20that.20a.20subclass.20is.20a.20kind.20of.20the.20supercla/near/220484887), for [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) whose [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) is a a [measurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space) with a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder), the generalized distribution function can be constructed in [Lean](https://leanprover-community.github.io/) as follows:

```
import measure_theory.lebesgue_measure
import tactic

noncomputable theory

open measure_theory

class probability_space (α : Type*) extends measure_space α :=
(is_probability_measure :  probability_measure volume)

namespace probability_space
variables {α : Type*} [probability_space α]

lemma volume_univ : volume (set.univ : set α) = 1 :=
is_probability_measure.measure_univ

lemma volume_le_one (S : set α) : volume S ≤ 1 :=
by rw ← @volume_univ α; exact measure_mono (set.subset_univ _)

def prob (S : set α) : ℝ := (volume S).to_real

def nnprob (S : set α) : nnreal := (volume S).to_nnreal

theorem volume_eq_nnprob (S : set α) : volume S = nnprob S :=
(ennreal.coe_to_nnreal $ ne_top_of_le_ne_top (by rintro ⟨⟩) (volume_le_one S)).symm

theorem prob_eq_nnprob (S : set α) : prob S = nnprob S := rfl

theorem nnprob_le_one (S : set α) : nnprob S ≤ 1 :=
ennreal.coe_le_coe.1 $ by rw ← volume_eq_nnprob; exact volume_le_one S

theorem prob_le_one (S : set α) : prob S ≤ 1 := nnprob_le_one _

theorem zero_le_prob (S : set α) : 0 ≤ prob S := nnreal.zero_le_coe

theorem nnprob_mono {S T : set α} (h : S ⊆ T) : nnprob S ≤ nnprob T :=
ennreal.coe_le_coe.1 $ by simpa only [← volume_eq_nnprob] using measure_mono h

theorem prob_mono {S T : set α} (h : S ⊆ T) : prob S ≤ prob T :=
nnreal.coe_le_coe.2 $ nnprob_mono h

end probability_space

theorem measurable.map_probability_measure {α β} [probability_space α] [measurable_space β]
  {f : α → β} (hf : measurable f) :
  probability_measure (measure.map f volume) :=
⟨by rw measure_theory.measure.map_apply hf is_measurable.univ;
    exact probability_space.volume_univ⟩

structure random_variable (α β : Type*) [probability_space α] [measurable_space β] :=
(outcome : α → β)
(is_measurable_outcome : measurable outcome)

variables {α β : Type*} [probability_space α] [measurable_space β]

namespace random_variable
instance : has_coe_to_fun (random_variable α β) := ⟨_,outcome⟩
variable (X : random_variable α β)
lemma measurable : measurable X := X.is_measurable_outcome

-- distribution of X
def induced (X : random_variable α β) : probability_space β :=
{ volume := measure.map X volume,
  is_probability_measure := X.measurable.map_probability_measure }

variables [preorder β]

-- distribution function of X
def CDF (x : β) : 
  ℝ := @probability_space.prob _ X.induced {c | c ≤ x}

lemma prob_eq_CDF (x : β) : X.CDF x = @probability_space.prob β X.induced {c | c ≤ x} := rfl

theorem zero_le_CDF (x : β) : 0 ≤ X.CDF x := 
begin
  rw prob_eq_CDF,
  exact (@probability_space.zero_le_prob β X.induced {c : β | c ≤ x}),
end
 
theorem CDF_le_one (x : β) : X.CDF x ≤ 1 := 
begin
  rw prob_eq_CDF,
  exact (@probability_space.prob_le_one β X.induced {c : β | c ≤ x}),
end

-- distribution function of X with codomain correctly restricted to [0,1]
def CDF_in_01 (x: β) : set.Icc (0 : ℝ) 1 := ⟨ X.CDF x, X.zero_le_CDF x, X.CDF_le_one x⟩

-- Example of a measurable codomain

variables [topological_space β] [order_closed_topology β] [opens_measurable_space β]

example (b : β) : is_measurable {c | c ≤ b} := is_closed.is_measurable is_closed_Iic

end random_variable
```

Comment: Every set can even be well ordered (Axiom of choice kind of stuff) but the ordered may not be compatible with the measurable structure. In your answer the assumption that ithe  metric space $Y$ is already ordered ( in defining $F_V$) is implicit. That is not the case in general. Also, for $F_V$ to be a useful thing, that is one can generate the $\mu_V$ from $F_V$ more structure is required (separability for instance).  In general one does have an order on $(Y,d)$.

Comment: If $(Y,d)$ is s Borel space (a Polish space for instance) then it is measurable isomorphic to $(0,1)$ and one can define an order in $Y$. The isomorphism however is not explicit, it is based on constructions that use the axiom of choice. That should not deter anybody to do probability on $(Y,d)$, one does not need order not cumulative distribution functions in this setting.